# How to wait for a specific script to load on page in Playwright?

Tags: javascript, playwright

In Cypress, `cy.intercept` can be used for this purpose:

```
cy.intercept('GET', 'https://hello.com/script.js').as('scriptLoaded');
cy.wait('@scriptLoaded', {timeout: 20000});
```

How do I do that in Playwright?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think what You are looking for are wait for request and/or response : https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-request

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).